# how to set the columns in an excel using Maatwebsite using laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5, maatwebsite-excel

Hi i have this download csv. Now my problem is i want to get the certain columns for my excel file not all fields from the database to be pulled to csv. Now my download csv works good and could download the data. Now i want that only certain columns to be displayed into my csv file. the `getCell` code wont work. This is my code below

```
//download csv all pending
    public function downloadExcelAllPending($type){
        $data = BookingHistory::orderBy('checkin_date', 'desc')->get()->toArray();

        return Excel::create('booking_history', function($excel) use ($data) {

        $excel->sheet('mySheet', function($sheet) use ($data)
        {

            $sheet->getCell('A1')->setValue('first_name');
            $sheet->fromArray($data);


         });

        })->download($type);
```

Now this line of code here  `$sheet->getCell('A1')->setValue('first_name');` won't work. Can someone help me figured this thing out?. Any help is muchly appreciated. TIA.

Comment: Which version of `maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel` are you using?

Comment: i think 2.1 if im not mistaken

Comment: how will i able to do that in my column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could select only the desired attributes when fetching the data from the database:

```php
public function downloadExcelAllPending($type)
{
    $data = BookingHistory::orderBy('checkin_date', 'desc')
        ->select([
            'checkin_date',
            // your other attributes
        ])
        ->get()
        ->toArray();

    return Excel::create('booking_history', function ($excel) use ($data) {
        $excel->sheet('mySheet', function ($sheet) use ($data) {
            $sheet->fromArray($data);
        });
    })->download($type);
}
```